# adding javascript to all shopify pages

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I wish to add a snippet to all pages of any shopify store. While I can add it to theme.liquid, for the thank you page, I believe I need to add it elsewhere. Is there any way I can bypass that and place the script tag at one place only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are on Shopify plus account you can't.

The only way to add script tags is via the Additional Scripts in the checkout settings page.

Answer (score 1):

You can include JavaScript on the storefront pages and the thank you page (aka the order status page) using Shopify's ScriptTag API: https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/scripttag

Comment: Can I add the script tag to asyncLoad function to thank you page with this API ?